# desktop application ui testing

Tags: java, ui, test-automation, desktop

Подскажите, как (каким инструментом) тестить ui desktop application написанное на java (нажатие клавиши и т.д)? Приведите пример или скинте ссылку на статью. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить воспользоваться классом `java.awt.Robot`

```
String text = "Hello world";
Robot robot = new Robot();

for (int n = 0; n < text.length(); n++) {
     int keyEvent = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(text.charAt(n));
     robot.keyPress(keyEvent);
     robot.keyRelease(keyEvent);
     robot.delay(1000);
 }

 robot.waitForIdle();

 Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
 BufferedImage printScreen = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
 File outputFile = new File("screenShot.jpg");
 ImageIO.write(printScreen, "jpg", outputFile);
```

Этот пример, печатает `text` и делает скриншот. С помощью данного класса, можно менять положение курсора, эмулировать нажатие с мыши и клавиатуры.

Еще один вариант, это использовать напрямую очередь событий. Самостоятельно добавляя туда свои `event'ы` возможна эмитация действий пользователя:

`java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(customEvent);`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой [Fest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.easytesting/fest-swing).

Эта библиотека сможет подключиться к тестироемому приложению, запустить его. Может выбирать значения из комбобокса, проверять, выбран ли чекбокс, нажимать кнопки, вводить текст, забирать текст и многое другое.

Она как раз расчитана на `ui тестирование` `swing` приложений.